# How reducers are called in redux after getting passed to the store?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I wonder how `rootReducer` is used in the official `redux` todo list example on https://redux.js.org/basics/example-todo-list. It looks like reducers are not getting called after the `rootReducer` is passed to the store.

```
import React from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { createStore } from 'redux'
import rootReducer from './reducers'
import App from './components/App'
​
const store = createStore(rootReducer)
​

render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

Comment: They get called when you `connect()` a component with `react-redux` to the store, scroll down a bit on the page: https://redux.js.org/basics/example-todo-list#container-components

Comment: Thanks!. Note: The dispatch function send an action to the store. Reducers inside store will receive the state and action then return/update the state.